# C++ Why do we use << instead of braces at std::cout?

Tags: c++, std, cout

Ive started c++ and im wondering, why I dont use at cout braces to give it an argument. Why do we use << ? Isnt cout also a function, so shouldnt we use braces?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  In it, check out the section on operator overloading.  It should also talk about what `cin` and `cout` actually are.

Comment: `cout` is an object, not a function. `<<` is an operator.

Comment: `std::cout` is not a function but an object with an overload for `operator<<`, you could have found that out by reading documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

Comment: As an aside to the above comments: "braces" means `{}`. Functions are called with _parentheses_: `()`

Comment: << is stream insertion operator, 
In C++ you can overload operators
And, at least for me - it is more comfortable to use it with << instead of braces

Comment: I think OP's question could be rephrased as, why use an overloaded operator when at the end of the day it's going to resolve to a method that is passed a parameter?

Comment: I think this question needs more details. It is possible that question was about functionality like: `format` in other languages (then those braces have more seance). In such case C++20 to the rescue: [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) or [std::format_to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to).

Comment: @Keiji -- in UK English, braces are what we in the US call parentheses. Which is why `{}` are often referred to as "curly braces".

Comment: @PeteBecker Do you have a source for that? _I'm_ from the UK, and here, "braces" always means `{}` as it does for you. I've _never_ heard of the word "braces" being used to mean "parentheses". I've also checked Wiktionary, which states that in typography, "braces" means `{}`, and makes no mention of it meaning "parentheses" or `()`, regardless of region.

Comment: @Keiji -- well, I have to bow to authority. <g> I've seen "braces" used that way, and thought it was a UK thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of std::cout by [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is:

> The global objects std::cout and std::wcout control output to a stream
> buffer of implementation-defined type (derived from std::streambuf),
> associated with the standard C output stream stdout.

In your case, the operator << is used as an [operator overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).
This means that when we write an expression like `std::cout << "hi";` it will execute the overloaded function which looks something like this :

```
operator<<(std::cout, std::string);
```

This overloaded function will executed when it sees on the left side of the << operator an object of cout and on the right side an object of std::string

**Also note that cout is not a function, it is an object.**

Comment: I think that adding the bit shift information will confuse the OP more.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Agree, I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is an [operator overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), meaning it's just syntactic sugar for the equivalent code:

```
operator<<(cout, "Hello World");
```

Or, when `operator<<` is a member function (which happens to be the case for `std::cout`):

```
cout.operator<<("Hello World");
```

Comment: thats not quite true because there are member `operator<<` and non-member `operator<<`

Comment: for example `operator<<(std::cout, 42);` will fail to compile